# Why can't I display images in such a way? 

Tags: php, image, joomla

**SOLVED: I used a relative path to folder.**

Please help me understand why I can't display images in Joomla in such a way:

```
$path= JURI::root();

$previewImgPath = $path.'images'.DS.'folder'.DS.'images'.DS.$id.'/folder';
```

I got:

```
Warning: opendir(http://www.domain.com/joomla/images/folder/images/4/folder/)    [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: not implemented in ... on line 61
```

What way is correct to display images using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a relative path to a directory, something like `images/folder/images/4/folder/`. opendir() doesn't work with HTTP resources.

Try this:

```
$path= JURI::base();

$previewImgPath = $path.'images'.DS.'folder'.DS.'images'.DS.$id.'/folder';
```

Answer (score 1):

`JURI::root()` returns the base *URL* of the site. To get the base *path* of the site, use [`JPATH_BASE` or an equivalent for the appropriate version](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_find_your_absolute_path) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a dir with HTTP.

Use something like :

```
opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/joomla/images/folder/images/4/folder/');
```